# Protractor can't detect Angular 5 on deployed application

Tags: angular, protractor, cucumber, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I am trying to create a repository with E2E tests for my web application using Protractor and Cucumber. I have started with this repository: https://github.com/spektrakel-blog/angular-protractor-cucumber

When I am forcing Protractor to treat the application as a regular webpage, the tests run fine. Test runner is interacting with the application and expecting some outcome. The thing is, that I would like to make Protractor detect Angular in order to wait for zones to be stable before checking 'Then' asserts.

Here is my protractor.conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--no-sandbox']
    }
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://<ci-server-address>/',

  specs: [
    './e2e/features/*.feature'
  ],

  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),

  cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['./e2e/steps/**/*.ts'],
    strict: true,
    format: [
      'json:reports/summary.json'
    ],
    dryRun: false,
    compiler: []
  },

  onPrepare() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
  }
};
```

In short - the tests run with the following config, but when I remove `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`, I get the following error: `Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 30 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application.`.

Things I have tried so far (with no improvement):

- adding `ng-app` to the `<body>` tag
- checking `window.getAllAngularRootElements()` - returns `app-root` correctly
- checking `window.getAllAngularTestabilities()` - returns a `Testability` object
- launching the tests on Chrome (with or without sandbox)
- launching the tests on Firefox
- trying both the CI server with our application deployed and local env with `ng serve`

I am using the latest versions of Protractor, Cucumber, Chai and TypeScript. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It is stange that you have working solution and ask why did not work some other things. Why you can not just use working one? What advantanges you would like to get?

Comment: Where did I write that I have a working solution?

Comment: `When I am forcing Protractor to treat the application as a regular webpage, the tests run fine.` this one. I just want to understand maybe you try to resolve  the issue (definetly, it is the issue), but you might choose another way.

Comment: When Protractor is not able to detect Angular, it's not able to wait for resolving the zones. In such case, I need to put timeouts in my E2E tests in order to them to pass. This is unacceptable, not to mention that I'm using Protractor *because* of that Angular integration. ;)

Comment: why you could not to wait the zonez by `explicit` waiters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a potential **Zone** issue to me. Angular depends on [ZoneJS](https://github.com/angular/zone.js) (ngZone). It is not that uncommon to run into this error when using any asynchronous javaScript functions such as `setTimeout()`, `setInterval()`, etc...

The reason being is that ZoneJS monkey patches those functions and it does so out of the context of the Angular zone. At which point when Protractor is trying to connect to your application it no longer is running in the Angular Zone and therefor Protractor will *hang* and eventually timeout with the error you're getting.

If I were you I would **take a look at your application for any asynchronous functions that ZoneJS monkey patches**. Also in general, look for anything in your code that is running outside the context of your applications zone.

Here is a good article on ZoneJS that not only helps you understand ZoneJS, but also lists the functions that are monkey patched [Understanding ZoneJS](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/22/understanding-zones.html)

Comment: Once you ignore synchronization, you should not have a zone problem because the browser should not wait for Angular stability. So if you remove the `ignoreSynchronization` and you are on an Angular app, it can be a zone issue. I like this answer and might put bets on this.

Comment: This solved it for us! I've been trying to figure out what happened to our Protractor automation forever and would have never thought of this. Thank you!

Comment: This seems like a good track! Thank you very much, I'll check this out during the weekend.

Comment: In the end it turned out that we had ```setInverval``` somewhere in the app that should be run outside of Angular zone. Thank you very much, your suggestion was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Verify that your app actually gets stable:

```
  constructor(zone:NgZone)
  {
    zone.onStable.subscribe(()=> window.console.info('onStable'));
    zone.onUnstable.subscribe(()=> window.console.info('onUnstable'));
    zone.onMicrotaskEmpty.subscribe(()=> window.console.info('onMicrotaskEmpty'));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, by using your code I was quickly able to verify that I have in fact problems with using zones in my app. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below options

```
// CSS Selector for the element housing the angular app - this defaults to
// body, but is necessary if ng-app is on a descendant of <body>.
rootElement: 'body',

// The timeout in milliseconds for each script run on the browser. This should
// be longer than the maximum time your application needs to stabilize between
// tasks.
allScriptsTimeout: 3600 * 1000,

// How long to wait for a page to load.
getPageTimeout: 3600 * 1000,
```

and if your angular page take more time to load the page try to disable the animations with below code

```
    var disableNgAnimate = function () {
        angular.module('disableNgAnimate', []).run(['$animate', function ($animate) {
            $animate.enabled(false);
        }]);
    };
    browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);
```

Hope the above solutions helps you. `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` is deprecated  try using `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);` refer [here](https://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts) for more inputs

Comment: `ignoreSynchronization` is deprecated but still works. It is preferred to use the `waitForAngularEnabled` and setting it to false. See https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/02746dd37726b2647f8f8dbeb1152cd7f902acb0/lib/browser.ts#L230

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, I've already tried increasing the timeouts with no positive result. Also, we don't use Angular animations module. By the way, your code seems like written in AngularJS, and I'm using Angular (5.2 to be exact).

Answer (score 0):

protractor/globals have been removed from v4.0.9 , now we can simply import protractor helpers directly from protractor namespace which is much cleaner.

Example:

```
import {browser} from 'protractor';
```

Answer (score -1):

trying remove `baseUrl: 'http://<ci-server-address>/',` in protractor conf.js

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem - the browser opens correct page, just hangs and does nothing. Still, I've tried it and got the same results. FYI< I'm running the tests like that: `protractor --baseUrl http://url-to-my-ci-server`.

Comment: The page opened by `http://url-to-my-ci-server` is an Angular page or not?

Comment: Have you tried move the `browser.get('http://url-to-my-ci-server')` into test case and remove it from `baseUrl` conf.js and don't specify it in cmd line too.  If still not fix the issue,  try latest protractor

Comment: When I did so, there was the same result, just with a bit different error message: `Could not find Angular on page http://server-name/login : angular never provided resumeBootstrap`. I'm already using the latest version of Protractor - 5.3.1.

Comment: How to about to prepare an new spec to test another Angular app, like Angular official website: https://angular.io/  to  see whether the issue comes from your code and the dependencies.

Comment: I think I've tried that already. I'll take a look once more if everything else fails. Thanks!